# Multiple Child Themes

Tags: child-theme

I have a quick question:

Is it possible to have multiple child themes activated at once? I need to have many different page templates activate at once.  If it's not possible how can I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible.  You can only have one theme activated at any given time.

However, you can add as many page templates to a single theme as you want.  They just need to be in separate files.  For example, my theme contains:

- `page.php` ← Standard page template
- `page-archive.php` ← Page template for special archive pages
- `page-blog.php` ← Page template for a custom blog page
- `page-landing.php` ← Page template for special marketing campaign landing pages

You can build any hierarchy you want, so long as each page template file includes the regular page template header:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: About Page
*/
?>
... The rest of your regular template file continues below ...
```